# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{n+1}e^{\frac{x^2}{n+1}}dx$

Tags: analysis

I have a problem with evaluating $$\int_{0}^{n+1}e^{\frac{x^2}{n+1}}dx.$$ In subsequent steps I come upon counting integral $\int e^{x^2}dx$ which is quite problematic.  If it is not possible to count (in my opinion it's not workable), maybe is there a way to count the limit $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{n+1}e^{\frac{x^2}{n+1}}dx$$ because this is what I want to know eventually.

Comment: Consider the change of variables $t=\frac{x}{\sqrt{n+1}}$.

Comment: In which way does it help? Using this method we still meet a problem with $\int e^{x^2} dx$.

Comment: You do not need to know the antiderivative of $e^{x^2}$, just use the [comparison tests](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/comparison-test-for-improper-integral-convergence-divergence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest work around:
$$
e^{\frac{x^2}{n+1}}\ge 1\implies\int_0^{n+1}e^{\frac{x^2}{n+1}}\,dx\ge\int_0^{n+1}1\,dx=n+1\to +\infty,\quad n\to+\infty.
$$

---

Edit: If you need to estimate $\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{n+1}e^{\frac{x^2}{n+1}}\,dx$ then you can use the better bound $e^t\ge 1+t$, i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{n+1}e^{\frac{x^2}{n+1}}\,dx\ge\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{n+1}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n+1}\right)\,dx=\frac{n+1+\frac{(n+1)^2}{3}}{n}\to+\infty.
$$

---

Edit 2: To calculate the limit of
$$
Q=\frac{\int_0^{n+1}e^{\frac{x^2}{n+1}}\,dx}{\int_0^{n}e^{\frac{x^2}{n}}\,dx}
$$
we change the variable
$$
\int_0^{a}e^{\frac{x^2}{a}}\,dx=\left[t=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a}}\right]=\sqrt{a}\int_0^{\sqrt{a}}e^{t^2}\,dt,
$$
to get
$$
Q=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\frac{\int_0^{\sqrt{n+1}}e^{t^2}\,dt}{\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}e^{t^2}\,dt}.
$$
We use then L'Hospital's rule
$$
\lim Q=\lim \frac{\int_0^{\sqrt{n+1}}e^{t^2}\,dt}{\int_0^{\sqrt{n}}e^{t^2}\,dt}=
\lim \frac{e^{n+1}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}}{e^n\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}}=e.
$$

Comment: Yes, thanks, but is there a way to evaluate it without inequalities? Because if I would like to count a limit from this expression divided by $n$ it would be a problem

Comment: @Lover Divided by $n$ still $+\infty$, see the edit.

Comment: And the last question: what if I want to estimate $  \dfrac{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int _{0}^{n+1}e^{\frac{x^2}{n+1}}dx}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int _{0}^{n}e^{\frac{x^2}{n}}dx}$?

Comment: @Lover See more edits.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now everything is clear